# codeigniter how to get infomation of a row

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am making a function is when customer click the quickview button it will be open the modal have a infomation about that product, but i don't know how to do this, i try some method but not working, so  please help me.

This is my view :

```
        <div class="row">
                <h4>Feauture Product</h4>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="product">
                  <?php foreach ($infolist as $info_key){ ?>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                       <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/product/viewpd/<?php echo $info_key->id; ?>"><img src="http://wingsacessorios.com.br/public/img/vertical/img-home05.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h5 class="text-justify">Name product: <?php echo $info_key->name; ?></h5>
                        <p class="text-justify">Price: <?php echo $info_key->price.' VNĐ'; ?></p>
                        <p class="text-center"> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tocart(<?php echo $info_key->id ?>)" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" ><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"  aria-hidden="true"></i> Buy Now</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Quick View</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <?php }?>
                </div>

                <!-- Small modal alert when click add cart -->
                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header" style="padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="background-color:transparent;color:#000000;">Alert from website !</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <h5>Added product to your cart!</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal quickview -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

if i put modal quickview code in for each loop it just display infomation of first product

Comment: Note that it is best to use `<?php foreach (...): ?>` `<?php endforeach; ?>` instead of `<?php foreach (...) { ?>` `<?php } ?>` in template code (that mixes PHP and HTML) because of better readability.

Comment: I did change that in my answer below but forgot to mention it.  Good reminder for everyone too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open what you have above you'll need to open the modal with

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Launch demo modal
</button>
```

pay special attention to the 'data-target'.  that must match the ID of your modal div:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"... <---
```

If you have multiple products on the same page your best bet will be to generate modals programmatically with Bootstrap JS Modal.js plugin

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

**edit**

This is one way to do what I believe you're looking for.  I may have missed a variable echo, but the basics are there.

```
 <?php foreach ($infolist as $info_key): ?>
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/product/viewpd/<?php echo $info_key->id; ?>"><img src="http://wingsacessorios.com.br/public/img/vertical/img-home05.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h5 class="text-justify">Name product: some product</h5>
                    <p class="text-justify">Price: 12 VND</p>
                    <p class="text-center"> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tocart(<?php echo $info_key->id; ?>)" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cartModal<?php echo $info_key->id; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"  aria-hidden="true"></i> Buy Now</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $info_key->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Quick View</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Small modal alert when click add cart -->
            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="cartModal<?php echo $info_key->id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header" style="padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="background-color:transparent;color:#000000;">Alert from website !</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5>Added product <?php echo $info_key->id; ?> to your cart!</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal quickview -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $info_key->id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Product <?php echo $info_key->id; ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: no, i mean how to display infomation when you click quick view it will be display infomation of that product, example : i have 4 product and when i click quick view of product 1, the modal will display infomation of product 1, quick view 2 will display infomation of product 2.... that is i mean.

Comment: you are awesome :D :D

Comment: Glad to help.  Don't forget to click the checkmark beside my answer if you feel it's the correct solution.

Comment: i did it :) tks you again :D